# Uniquely identify a window

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to uniquely identify a window in Emacs?

There is `window-number-mode` but the generated IDs change when one adds a new window to the frame.

Comment: Every window is uniquely identified by its window object.  So, yes it's very much possible.  What do you want to do?

Comment: Programatically sending text from a given window to other. Which I am doing already but it can get unaccurate if 'popup' windows appear. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to say more about how you can know which window you want.

Comment: Let's suppose I want to *enumerate* all windows with an id which won't change if I change the displayed buffers or add/remove windows/frames. That way I could set the point (i.e. the active cursor) to one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to read up on windows in the Elisp manual.  The windows can be identified by the objects returned by functions such as `selected-window`, `next-window`, `get-buffer-window`, etc...

Comment: Nice, thanks! calling `select-window` on one of the values you mention addresses my issue.